React Native Signature Canvas Pad overflowing and styling issues in iOS app
I'm implementing an e-signature feature in my React Native iOS application using react-native-signature-canvas. However, I'm encountering two main issues:
The signature pad is getting cut off at the right end, overflowing its container.
I'm having difficulty applying custom styling to wrap the pad inside a rectangular container.
I've tried various approaches including adjusting padding, using SafeAreaView, and modifying the webStyle, but the issues persist.
Here's the current webStyle I'm using:
const style = `
  .m-signature-pad--footer {display: none; margin: 0px;}
  .m-signature-pad--body {border: 3px dashed #8863FB;}
  .m-signature-pad {box-shadow: none; border: none;}
`;


I've attempted numerous solutions, but I can't get the canvas to display completely within its container while maintaining the desired custom styling.
Here are some images illustrating the current output:
RN signature canvas image with styling
Image without styling
My questions are:
How can I prevent the signature pad from overflowing its container on the right side?
What's the correct way to apply custom styling to create a rectangular container around the signature pad?
Are there any specific considerations for iOS when using react-native-signature-canvas?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Any Luck? I am having exact same problem
